# How to resolve my unearned income issue with the IRS?

Tags: taxes, income-tax, income

On Friday Sept 16, someone in the building gave us mailing from the IRS. They were holding it for us and claim that they have been holding it for about 2-3 weeks. The paperwork informs us that the IRS is claiming that the income that I reported in 2019 is now considered unearned unless I prove otherwise by August 29, 2022.

When I got the paperwork I repeatedly called/faxed the person who is handling this case over 3-4 business days and left multiple vm's furnishing my S.S. # and 2 phone #'s and an email how to contact me and that I have pay stubs from an employer that shows that it is earned income but I have not heard back from them despite that the vm says that they'll return my call within 1 business day.

The paperwork states that if I do not reply by that date, "we'll send you a statutory notice of deficiency that gives you 90 days to petition the United States Tax Court."

I live and work outside of the U.S., I have always filed my 1040. I am not sure what made them think that in 2019 anything changed. They had no issue with the 2018 1040 with the same employer, same salary. I wish to get this resolved as I do not want this happening again for 2020 and onward. It's the same employer, same pay stubs.

Can anyone advise me what to do to resolve this?

Here are two pages, [image: page 1] [image: page 2]of the documentation packet, maybe someone would have more ideas how to resolve this now.

This is the explanation from the IRS:[image]

(The other pages are a form 12203 to request for appeals review and form 872 consent to extend the time to assess tax and form 4549 report of income tax examination changes where they changed my income to unearned and do my whole 1040 calculations over based on that change. They sent everything 2x, one to me and one to my wife as we report jointly.

Comment: Unearned income doesn't normally cause a deficiency; is this income you excluded using FEIE (form 2555[EZ]) they claim should not have been excluded? If 'building' is outside the US -- i.e. they _mailed_ to a non-US address, as opposed to you retrieving it from someplace with a US address -- the normal 90-day period to file in Tax Court is extended to 150 days, see 26 USC 6213. IRS knows the law and if the address they used was non-US the notice should reflect this.

Comment: Obligatory point: Are you *sure* the "mailing from the IRS" is not a scam? Are you able to confirm the contact info in the letter starting from known valid contact info for the IRS? I'm seeing a yellow flag that (1) the notice doesn't seem to make sense for your situation and (2) in response to the letter's instructions you have "left multiple [voicemails] furnishing my S.S. #" (something a scammer might want). Perhaps others familiar with this type of notice can help you identify whether the content and instructions are normal or suspicious.

Comment: They mailed two full packets, 1 for myself and my wife. The documentation has all my numbers I reported that year but the earned income was adjusted to unearned. They are not asking me for anything. Only if I wish to agree I can pay but I can choose to disagree. It has my last for Tax payer id. Everything looks legit to me. How could I tell if it would be a scam? Any suggestions?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I didn't leave it out. It looks to me that since I am abroad, they are challenging me to prove that it's earned income. They also are asking me for consular report of birth abroad for all my children and my and my wife's citizenship. I have no idea what brought this up. I have been filing abroad for 20 years. There is not a mention of any wrong doing. My issue is they the person does not answer the phone nor call me back and that I 17 days past the deadline but  there was a reason for this.

Comment: FYI, I added more information in  my question and two pages, perhaps that will help others suggest what to do now and determine if this is legit (which it looks to me but I am not an expert in this)

Comment: I didn't say you left anything out; FEIE (Foreign Earned Income Exclusion) applies if you live in a foreign country substantially all year (I assume though you didn't specifically say so) and have income from employment (or self-employment), and if so you _report_ on 1040 line 1 as usual can but also fill out 2555[EZ] which puts this income up to a limit ($105.9k in 2019) on schedule 1 and line 8a, with the result it isn't counted in your taxable income and thus isn't taxed. If you _haven't_ been doing this, IRS may have flagged it as anomalous -- although you aren't _required_ ...

Comment: ... to take advantage of options that reduce your tax, most people do. And if you didn't, I'm still mystified by how changing earned (but unexcluded) income to unearned could possibly cause an increase in tax. Without posting personal info, can you be any more specific about what the adjustments were? Did they refer to particular forms, schedules, lines, or boxes? Chapters or paragraphs of the instructions, or worksheets (by name or number)?

Comment: When you fax your responses, is that using an electronic service which would also save a copy of the faxed items? Make sure you keep the cover sheet and a copy of the documentation sent. You are in a situation where proof of your attempt to contact the IRS may become necessary. Phone calls, if they are not successful in reaching the agent, are proof of nothing. Communicate via writing if at all possible, including through registered mail to indicate proof of mailing date. Save copies of everything.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 It seems you may not be familiar with FEIE. If the income is 'unearned', it would not qualify for FEIE, and therefore would be taxed [possibly to be reduced by 'foreign tax credits' for taxes paid in country of residence].

Comment: FYI, I found form 884-A in the packet and added it here. Perhaps it can help with someone thinking of how to get out of this. The issue is that I am late and that there is no one who answers the phone including the International Taxpayer Service Call Center to speak with and show that it IS earned income from a regular job.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon: FEIE exclusion is exactly what I suggested in my first comment, which OP apparently rejected, but unclearly -- which is why I explicitly said "if you didn't" use FEIE I didn't understand "changing earned (but unexcluded) income". However, [in a subsequent Q](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/152875/can-submitting-a-form-12203-request-for-appeals-help-me-in-my-situation-when-i-a) we see it was CTC and ACTC, the latter of which does depend on earned income and in fact _prohibits_ taking FEIE. (In 2021 'Rescue' changes this for residents, but not OP.)

Answer (score 2):

You're being audited for the tax year 2019. In the audit the examining officer found some mistakes on your return and proposed changes (changing earned income to unearned income). They're asking for specific information, including all the documents they've listed. Form 106 specifically would prove that the income is earned. I'm *guessing* you're also claiming EITC? They're requiring information that would be needed to substantiate that claim.

When you're audited it's best to have a representative deal with that. In audit, you can be represented by an attorney, EA or a CPA (US). There are quite a few US-licensed tax professionals you can find locally in Israel, or hire someone in the US.

I strongly advise you against doing it yourself. As with any legal action initiated against you by the government, being represented by a licensed and experienced professional will help you tremendously. Yes, that would cost you. Alternatively you can try doing it on your own, but seems like it didn't work all that well for you so far. You may want to consider to just accept the changes and pay the tax, if your cost-effect analysis shows that fighting it is more expensive.

In terms of timeline, since you live abroad deadlines may be extended, some are extended statutorily. That said, if you miss the deadline - you miss the opportunity to resolve the case. If you miss the deadline to provide the information - you miss the opportunity to appeal to the IRS itself, you'll wait for the statutory deficiency letter to appeal to the Tax Court. If you miss that one - you'll have to pay the tax and appeal to the Federal District court for refund. If you miss that - you missed out.

Comment: ty.Is there anything I can do proactively instead of waiting for mail to arrive? It's been 24 days since the deadline, I do not want to wait longer. Can I call anyone? Also, I am abroad, can I work this out from here?

Comment: You/your representative can call proactively to check where it stands right now and see if the letter can be accelerated. I suggest asking a professional to do that and not trying doing it yourself since the matter has escalated by now quite a bit. But... bureaucracy takes time.

Comment: Where can the rep call? Why can't I? If all they want it proof that I earned the money, why can't I handle this myself as opposed to paying who knows how much to show them that I have been reporting correctly. I just don't know where to call and be proactive. The rep that is the paperwork doesn't respond.

Comment: please see my comment above where I added more information. I would prefer to handle this myself if I could. I suspect that a professional will cost thousands to help resolve this.

Comment: @MrMonee not sure why my answer warranted a downvote, but updated it for you. You can most definitely handle it yourself, if you want. Worked very well for you so far.

Comment: littleadv: FYI, I didn't downvote it and it looks like it was removed. Can you explain wha you meant by "Worked very well for you so far"?

Comment: @MrMonee If I understand correctly you've been handling your taxes on your own without any professional help. As the result you're now stuck in a situation where the IRS has made an adverse decision against you and you don't know what to do about it. Your behavior so far suggest absolute ignorance as to the rules and to the laws, and that's not a negative statement - it's true for almost anyone in the US, not to mention expats. You *can* try and handle it yourself. You're *likely* to only make matters worse, as you've done so far, by doing so. I was being sarcastic. ...

Comment: @MrMonee ... I don't know how many people you know who went through a legal process initiated against them by the government, but ask around and see how many you can find, and of those - how many were able to go through it without representation *at all*, let alone were able to go through it without representation and *win*.

Comment: All the years, I used a tax software. I didn't "wing it". I have no idea why, perhaps this is a standard audit, but they sent me a form 4564 to prove that my income is in fact earned which I believe I can prove but my issue is that I only got this form (and form 4549 and other forms) 2 weeks after the deadline and the IRS simply doesn't answer any of my many calls' vm's and faxes so I can work this out. Sending this to tax court sounds like a huge slap for someone who always files and keeps attempting to get a live person to explain/prove it all.

Comment: If there any chance to avoid the legal process or is it after the point of no return? How to determine this?

Comment: @MrMonee someone asked that before, but I'll ask again - *why* have you received it so late? Was it sent to the address you listed on your tax return? If so - are you actually living there? You see, professionals don't only know how to use the formulas your software uses. They also know the rules, the regulations, the exceptions, and the shortcuts. The IRS has a separate phone line for professionals. Professionals can file motions and appeals, they know *how* and *where* and *when*. You don't.

Comment: @MrMonee what do you mean "avoid"? You *are* in the legal process already.

Comment: The address is our apartment that we rent out (rental income is reported each year). That is our official address for mailings and what I put on my 1040. We have moved 3 times since we rented it out so it doesn't make sense to put down a rental apartment on the 1040 which seems to be changed when it makes sense to move. We got it late because the tenants simply didn't bother to inform us until Sept 16. The forms just sat by them. No other reason.

Comment: @MrMonee yes, but you see - now you cannot claim that the IRS didn't give you enough time to respond, since the IRS sent the notice to the address you gave them. It is your responsibility to check your mail. You're complaining here that you got the letter 2 weeks after the deadline, but this is a problem you created yourself. So what argument are you going to bring to the IRS when you ask them to reconsider the deficiency?

Comment: I agree with what you said but the bottom line is that it IS earned income. I just need someone to talk to and show them my pay stubs. The lateness was not intended and if you can see that I have proof of earned income, there would be no reason to suspect me of stalling. I have the proof all along. It should be clear that this isn't criminal. I am going to attach more proof that you can see that they are only contesting that it's unearned. They do not explain why they are saying this but I am happy to work it out as I have whatever they want.

Comment: @MrMonee you're missing the point. You were given time to make your case to the IRS agent and you didn't. The IRS agent concluded what they concluded and moved on. They no longer hold the case. Even if you reach them over the phone - that's what they'll tell you. The next step is the statutory deficiency letter and the Tax Court where you petition against it. That's the process.

Comment: @MrMonee all that said, if you find a professional who's whole practice is dealing with IRS audits - they may know some other ways to handle this which may save you time and money. Which is why I suggest you find one.

Comment: This is all excellent advice from @littleadv, but I am going to add another suggestion which is to get a post office box in the foreign country where you reside, and not rely on tenants.